# how to fetch each variable from merged session array in ci

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I stored all the product details into a session variable cart and newly added product details stored in an array new. These details are merged together and I got an array like this

```
    Array(
          [0] => Array(
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 2
                    [length_id] => 1
                    [length] => 12"
                    [color] => Black , Natural Black
                    [quantity] => 345
                    [image] => http://localhost/shopping_cart/shop/uploads/product/deepwave.jpg
                    [totalprice] => 1500
                    [pdt_name] => Deep Wavy
                    [pdt_description] => Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
                    [pdt_image] => deepwave.jpg
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 3
            [length_id] => 1
            [length] => 12"
            [color] => Black , Natural Black
            [quantity] => 234
            [image] => http://localhost/shopping_cart/shop/uploads/product/loose wavy.jpg
            [totalprice] => 2500
            [pdt_name] => Loose Wavy
            [pdt_description] => Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the 
            [pdt_image] => loose wavy.jpg
        )

)
```

Comment: What is your expected output and please format your code and What you have tried so far

Comment: You must edit the format , its not quite well .

Answer (score 0):

Get session variable in controller and use for loop to iterate through it.

```
$product_details = $this->session->userdata('cart');

foreach($product_details as $item){
    echo $item['product_id']; /* likewise use for each field you need. */
}
```